# Make a text field plus a button full width together

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im attempting to have a text field plus its button full width together of their parent container.

**The HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="searchit" id="homesearch" placeholder="Search here..." /><!----><input type="submit" name="searchitSubmit" id="homebtn" value="Search" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
.container{
    max-width:1200px;
}
#homesearch{
    border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    outline:none;
    width:700px;
    border-right:none;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
}
#homesearch:focus{
    border:1px solid #b8181e;
    border-right:none;
}
#homebtn{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#EC1D25;
    padding:10px 20px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border:1px solid #e4e4e4;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px solid #b8181e;
}
#homebtn:hover{
    background-color:#b8181e;
}
#homebtn:active{
    background-color:#b8181e;
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

The only possible way I could potentially think of doing this is with jQuery, but I wanted to see if I could avoid that and do it purely CSS. If not, then a solution via jQuery would be viable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I give your input and button `width` in percent (70%/30% for exemple).

I also add `float:left` to the input, and `float:right` to the button.

And I finally add a `box-sizing:border-box;` to both elements to prevent your paddings from oversizing width.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ema1ewhk/)